# Can't Change RadioButton Color to Black

Tags: java, android, xml, radio-button

I am trying to change the RadioButton color I have. I programmatically add RadioButtons, however after researching I am unable to change the color to a solid black border with a black filling when clicked. Here is my code where I add the buttons, I understand there may be considerations for both API Levels < 21 and > 21:

```
 public void addRadioButtonsWithFirebaseAnswers(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, int numberOfAnswers) {
    mPollAnswerArrayList = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAnswers; i++) {
        Log.e("Number of Answers", "The number of answers is " + numberOfAnswers);
        mPollAnswerArrayList.add(i, new RadioButton(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i).setId(i);
        String firebaseChild = String.valueOf(i + 1);
        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i).setText(dataSnapshot.child(POLL_ANSWERS_LABEL).child(firebaseChild).child("Answer").getValue().toString());
        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.radio_button_answer_text_size));
        mParams.setMargins((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.radio_question_margin_left), 0, 0, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.radio_question_margin_bottom));

        mPollQuestionRadioGroup.addView(mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i), mParams);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of selected radio button using selector

**selector_radio_btn/xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/checkbox_active" />
      <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/checkbox_inactive" />
</selector>
```

**checkbox_inactive.xml**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#53aade" />
</shape>
```

**checkbox_activi.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#53aade" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item left="5dp" right="5dp" top="5dp" bottom="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="#53aade" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

set selector_radio_btn.xml in radiobutton

```
mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i).setButtonDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_radio_btn));
```

Comment: Not sure if this is completely accurate - shouldn't the references be to drawables and not colors? android:drawable="@color/checkbox_active

Answer (score 0):

To address API < 21 and API > 21, I have done the following:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            mPollAnswerArrayList.get(indexCreated).setButtonTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
        } else {
            mPollAnswerArrayList.get(indexCreated).setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.black_ring);

        }
```

I have also added the drawable as below:

black_ring.xml in my drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="3dp"
    android:useLevel="false" >

    <solid android:color="@color/black" />

    <size
        android:height="25dp"
        android:width="25dp" />

</shape>
```